# Example of contraction operator on Banach space with nonzero fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

The proof of the fixed point theorem for a contraction on a general Banach space makes complete sense to me but I do not understand how this theorem is informative because it seems that the fixed point should just be zero in all cases (given that the contraction's repeated application drives the initial choice of point closer to zero and in any case a linear operator maps zero to zero). Could you please either provide a non-trivial example or an explanation why zero isn't just the fixed point in all cases?

Also, for $T$ such a contraction and $x$ an arbitrary nonzero point, why doesn't the naive reasoning that $\lim |T^n x| \leq \lim ||T^n|| |x|$ imply that $T^\infty x = 0$ (i.e. what subtle issue is there with the interchange of operations here that keeps us from this type of straightforward reasoning)?

Comment: what fixed point theorem are you referring to?

Comment: If $T$ is a contraction on a Banach space, the limit of its recursive application to an arbitrary point exists and is a fixed point in the Banach space.

Comment: Consider $T$ defined on $C([0,1])$ defined by $Tf(x) = \int_0^x f(y)\,dy$. I am not sure this 100% works but it should be close enough to give you ideas.

Comment: @offonatangent ofcourse a linear map maps $0$ to $0$. But this theorem does not talk about linear maps, it talks about any contractive map. Also, what Cameron Williams says is an operator, $Tf$ is a function and $Tf(x)$ is equal to the integral $\int_0^xf(y)dy$.

Comment: $T(x) = \cos(x)$ is a contraction on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Sorry, but $\cos$ isn't linear. Agree that my comment about $T$ the operator proposed by Cameron was mistaken. Now trying to work on why it is a linear contraction. @CameronWilliams, can you explain what norm you're using? For instance, if you take the sup norm, isn't the operator not necessarily as contraction, e.g. the norm of the constant function after application of $T$ doesn't change?

Comment: @offonatangent The theorem refers to any map, not only linear maps! what would be the point of talking about fixed points of linear maps when every linear map satisfies $0\mapsto0$?

Comment: Aren't there many different statements of the fixed point theorem? The one I'm working with is limited to linear maps. It's possible I'm dealing with a poorly stated version of the theorem . . . the fixed point is unique, so this statement really is not informative then.

Comment: @offonatangent Like I said, you might need to adjust it slightly. You could tighten it to $C([0,\frac{1}{2}])$ or modify the integrand slightly by throwing an extra function in there.